# Expandable Tree View in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make expandable tree view in android like below screen short 
[Expandable List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEz4e.png).
I have tried but i want it with explanation.
Hope will get better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a PR for Xamarin to include this (see [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/9044))

For the time being, you can use [ExpandableView NuGet](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/ExpandableView) which is quite simple:

```
<expandable:ExpandableView>
    <expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>
        //{YOUR MAIN VIEW HERE}
    </expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>
    <expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            //{YOUR DROP-DOWN MENU TEMPLATE HERE} you can use DataTemplateSelector too
        </DataTemplate>
    </expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>
</expandable:ExpandableView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin Community Toolkit package:

```
 xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

You have possibility to define a header, nest several expander, define the View as a Content or using a DataTemplate, define animations (`ExpandAnimationEasing`, `CollapseAnimationEasing`)...

```
<xct:Expander IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ExpandAnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicIn}"
                                             CollapseAnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicOut}">
    <xct:Expander.Header>
        <Label Text="Nested expander" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    </xct:Expander.Header>
    <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Margin="10" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black">
                <BoxView HeightRequest="50" Color="White" />
                <BoxView HeightRequest="50" Color="Red" />
                <BoxView HeightRequest="50" Color="White" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
</xct:Expander>
```

#### Note from the documentation

> The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a ListView or CollectionView. At this time we recommend not using a Expander in one of these controls.

#### Resource

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander

Repo: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit